# Different overload method is chosen, depending from where it's called with a null parameter

Tags: c#, overloading

I have a class with an overloaded Format method.

```
 class FormatStuff
 {
    public static string Format(object arg)
        => HandleObjectStuff();

    public static string Format(IEnumerable<object> args)
        => HandleListStuff();
 }
```

Now, when I call

```
FormatStuff.Format(null);
```

I end up in the second overload with the IEnumerable parameter.
But in my case, I call the method from within a function like this:

```
 public static string DoStuff(IEnumerable<int> intnumerable)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append(FormatStuff.Format(intnumerable));
     return sb.ToString();
 }
```

When I call this function like

```
DoStuff(null);
```

I end up in the first overload with the single object parameter, even though in both cases null is passed as the parameter.

Why is this and what can I do to end up in the second overload that matches the type of the DoStuff-parameter?

**Edit:**
The question has been marked as a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392957/overloading-null-ambiguity) one. I don't think that's entirely the case, because the salient point that helped me understand my problem was, that an `IEnumerable<int>` is not an `IEnumerable<object>`.
In general that means, that one cannot expect an IEnumerable of any type to be an IEnumerable of object, which I did not know.
This conclusion is not drawn in the mentioned post.

Comment: An `IEnumerable<int>` isn't an `IEnumerable<object>` so that overload doesn't apply.

Comment: Then why does it take the IEnumerable overload when I call the Format function directly with `FormatStuff.Format(null);`?

Comment: `null` is an `IEnumerable<object>` and that is 'more specific' than `object` so that overload is chosen. If you call `Format` with an `IEnumerable<int>` only the `object` overload applies. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/152602) which describes how overloads are resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading null ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392957/overloading-null-ambiguity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which overload to call (binding) is statically fixed for each invocation expression at compile-time (unless you use type `dynamic` at compile-time). Just because the expression you use for argument happens to evaluate to another type when the program runs, the overload will not magically change.

Examples:

```
FormatStuff.Format(null);
```

The compile-time type does not exist (null), but since there is an implicit conversion from the `null` literal to `object` and an implicit conversion from `null` to `IEnumerable<object>` as well, both overloads are candidates. In that case the overload with `IEnumerable<object>` is preferred because it is more specific.

```
FormatStuff.Format((object)null);
```

In this case the compile-time type of the expression is `object`, so only one overload applies, and that is used.

```
IEnumerable<int> intnumerable
// ...
FormatStuff.Format(intnumerable);
```

In the above case the compile-time type of what you pass is `IEnumerable<int>`. Here `int` is a value-type. An `IEnumerable<int>` is not an `IEnumerable<object>` at compile-time. **This is fixed at compile-time;** it does not matter whether `intnumerable` happens to be `null` at run-time, and if non-null, it does not matter what the actual type (some concrete class or struct implementing `IEnumerable<int>`) is at run-time.

```
IEnumerable<string> strEnumerable
// ...
FormatStuff.Format(strEnumerable);
```

Finally, in this case, since `string` is a reference type, the compile-time covariance of `IEnumerable<out T>` applies. So an `IEnumerable<string>` *is* an `IEnumerable<object>`. Therefore both overloads apply, and the most specific one is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, **your method must be able to distinguish** between the two method calls. 
When you pass `null` the `Format()` method doesn't know if your null is an `object` or `IEnumerable<object>` since both are of type object.
To solve your issue you can do one of the following:

- 1 Change the second method as `Format(IEnumerable<int> args)`

*OR*

- 2 Change the type signature of your method by adding optional arguments. Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5498202/6699069) as an example