# How to overload controller method in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, overloading

I'm trying to overload the method below because I don't want to pass a null for the optional parameter. So I read online that I could let overloads call each other. I was following this example:

[Is passing null in to a method acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498179/is-passing-null-in-to-a-method-acceptable)

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TesMethod (int? testID, int employeeID)
    {
        Excel excel = new Excel();
        excel.CreateExport(null, int employeeID);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
    }

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TesMethod (int employeeID)
    {
        Excel excel = new Excel();
        excel.CreateExport(int employeeID);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
    }
```

I would like one method to take the optional parameter int? testID and the other method to not take the optional parameter. How can I do this?

Any help is very much appreciated it.

Comment: why so difficult? You can have one method that takes `employeeID` and another that takes `testID` and `employeeID` ...  I don't see any reason of having optional parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @PeterB That's only a duplicate if you take this question literally instead of showing the OP what should be done

Comment: By the way, this code doesn't compile: `excel.CreateExport(int employeeID);`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to pass null, default to `null` instead. Following the below structure, you can pass in an `employeeID` and a `testID` if needed. You only need this method (and not two).

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TesMethod (int employeeID, int? testID = null)
{
    Excel excel = new Excel();
    excel.CreateExport(testID, employeeID);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
}
```